# how to make AutoCompleteTextView uneditable

Tags: android, android-studio, autocompletetextview

I am trying to implement dependent AutoCompleteTextView with minor change. I had successfully implemented them but, now I don't want user to be able to write anything in the **editText** and simply, give them only one option to **select them from dropdown**.
Along with this, one suggestion if anyone can say, I wantto implement something like that when user selects AutoCompleteTextView1 then dynamically AutoCompleteTextView2 shall appear in the UI to get selected.

```
parentDefectItem = new String[]{"parent1", "parent2"};
        subDefectItem1=new String[]{"Item1","Item2"};
        subDefectItem2=new String[]{"Item3","Item4"};

        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.defect_list_dropdown, parentDefectItem);
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.defect_list_dropdown, subDefectItem1);
        adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.defect_list_dropdown, subDefectItem2);
        defectAutoComp1.setThreshold(0);
        defectAutoComp1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        defectAutoComp1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(parentDefectItem[position].equals("parent1")){
                    defectAutoComp2.setThreshold(0);
                    defectAutoComp2.setAdapter(adapter2);
                }
                else{
                    defectAutoComp2.setThreshold(0);
                    defectAutoComp2.setAdapter(adapter3);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `android:editable="false"` in your AutoCompleteTextView

Answer (score 1):

Attribute `android:editable="false"` is deprecated. You can instead use `android:enabled="false"` in the XML. If you want to programmatically do it, use:

```
tv1.setEnabled(false);
```

For making other views dynamically appear as per values entered to your textview, you can use something like:

```
tv1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
              tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           } else {
              tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @yash, it worked for me and thanks for showing all possible ways for that which you know.